# Is there a way to make a conditional statement from text into an if statement?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, special-characters, boolean-logic

Let's say that I have a conditional statement in text:

```js
let conditional_text = "(A && B) || (A && !B)"
```

Is there a way to turn that into {see below} without a difficult and crazy function?

```js
if ((A && B) || (A && !B)) {...}
```

Is there a way, in JavaScript, to use those special character things (like using the \, %, and $ inside the text) instead?

Is it even possible to go from text to a true or false

Comment: On what language?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about an expression evaluator -- a piece of code that can parse a string using some form of grammar that your expressions are expected to follow,, substitute variable values, and calculate a result.   Whether that counts as "difficult and crazy" depends on your experience level, and what's offered in your target programming language.   Some languages offer an "eval" function as a built-in feature; in others, you'd have to write your own parser.

Comment: @Alejandro suppose JavaScript or ECMAScript? `eval()` is a dangerous function, and is also slower than the alternatives…